# Blog database design using EF 6

Tags: database-design, entity-framework-6, blogs

I have the following three table for my Blog app,

```
public class Blog
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ShortDesc { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public int BloggerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BloggerId")]
    public virtual Blogger blogger { get; set; }

}
public class Blogger
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisteredOn { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BlogId")]
    public List<Blog> BlogList { get; set; }

}

public class Comments
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public int BloggerId { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostedOn { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BlogId")]
    public virtual Blog blog { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BloggerId")]
    public virtual Blogger blogger { get; set; }
}
```

My question is:
Do I have to have some reference of my comments table into the Blog table ??
If the answer is NO than how to query to get the blogs which has some comments ??

Comment: I am not sure how to post the code in the stakeoverflow. So my first table in the above questions is partly visible in the code area and partly in the question text. Sorry for that.

Comment: Yes. Most f the time you'll fetch comments from the blog, so you need a `public List<Comment> comments .... ` propery in Blog class.

Comment: @infiniteRefactor ,  Thnaks for the response. I am curently using the below query to find the blogs with comments.  Do you see some issue doing that ??   Although I agree with your answer that Blog class should have reference to Comment class ,         

 var result =   context.Blog.Join(context.Comment, b => b.Id, c => c.BlogId, (b, c) => new { 
                
                    content = b.Content,
                    comment = c.Comment
                });

Comment: That seems ok functionally. In performance terms, it depends on your application. If you do not need the blog -> comment link very often then you'll be ok.